# fill a 2D array as a diamond shape

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I want to fill my array with struct in a way that it will look like this [image]

I have this code so far :

```
               `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                  for (int j = 0; j <=(n - i); j++)
                    //i should fill m[,] here
                  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                      //i should fill m[,] here
                  for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                     //i should fill m[,] here

            }

            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                  for (int j = 0; j < (n - i); j++)
                        //i should fill m[,] here
                  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                     //i should fill m[,] here
                  for (int k = 1; k < i; k++)
                      //i should fill m[,] here

            }`
```

but I 'm a little bit confused with  the index .
how can I adopt this code?

Comment: *"adopt"*? It's unclear what you are trying to *"adopt"* since that code doesn't do anything

Comment: think about it in terms of a formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's unclear wether the array always has the size 5 I'll assume it has the size n with n being odd and n > 0 (The size is the x *and* the y size, as I assume that your matrix is quadratic). Then there are several ways to reach the goal your trying to reach, I'll try to present you one I thought of.

First of all we have to think about the array - as it's the easiest way, I'll assume it consists of boolean values (even though you said *"I want to fill my array with struct"*, but as I'm not quite sure what you wanted to say with that and wether you really meant a `struct`, I'll let this up to you, as this shouldn't be the most difficult part):

```
var matrix = new bool[n,n];
```

Then we have to evalueate which fields have to be filled. Therefore we must realize a few things:

1. The filled fields are always central in their line
2. The first and last line always have one filled item
3. The following line always has two more/less filled items, so that the offset is one more than in the previous line
4. The center line has most items and is the turning point in the amount of filled items

As a first step in developing the algorithm, I'd write a function to fill lines of the array with specific amounts of fields:

```
private static void FillLine(int line, int count, bool[,] matrix)
{
    //Firstly we have to evaluate the offset:
    var offset = (matrix.GetLength(0) - count) / 2;
    //Then we have to fill the line
    for (var x = offset; x < offset + count; x++)
        matrix[x, line] = true;
}
```

Now we simply have to fill the lines for the whole array:

```
public static void FillDiamond(bool[,] matrix)
{
    var count = 1;
    for (var line = 0; line < matrix.GetLength(1) / 2; line++)
    {
        FillLine(line, count, matrix);
        count += 2;
    }
    FillLine(matrix.GetLength(1) / 2, count, matrix);
    count = 1;
    for (var line = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; line > matrix.GetLength(1) / 2; line--)
    {
        FillLine(line, count, matrix);
        count += 2;
    }
}
```

Now in a console application you could use this like that:

```
using System;

namespace SO_c
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (n < 1 || n % 2 == 0)
                    continue;
                var matrix = new bool[n, n];
                FillDiamond(matrix);
                for (var y = 0; y < matrix.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x < matrix.GetLength(0); x++)
                        Console.Write(matrix[x, y] ? "█" : " ");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
        private static void FillLine(int line, int count, bool[,] matrix)
        {
            //Firstly we have to evaluate the offset:
            var offset = (matrix.GetLength(0) - count) / 2;
            //Then we have to fill the line
            for (var x = offset; x < offset + count; x++)
                matrix[x, line] = true;
        }

        public static void FillDiamond(bool[,] matrix)
        {
            var count = 1;
            for (var line = 0; line < matrix.GetLength(1) / 2; line++)
            {
                FillLine(line, count, matrix);
                count += 2;
            }
            FillLine(matrix.GetLength(1) / 2, count, matrix);
            count = 1;
            for (var line = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; line > matrix.GetLength(1) / 2; line--)
            {
                FillLine(line, count, matrix);
                count += 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can result in output like that:

[image: Example result]

That's it! Now you should get your diamond for every matrix that fits the rules :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to calculate the center of the grid and fill in each row, from the center column. In each successive row, we increment the number of blocks we fill in on each side of the center column until we get to the center row, and then we decrement the number of blocks we fill in until we get to the end.

To determine how many blocks to put on each side of the center column for any given row, we can use the row index for the calculation.

Working our way from the top down to the center, the row index represents the number of blocks to add. So, for row index 0, we add 0 blocks on either side of the center column, row index 1 we add 1 block on each side, until we get to the center.

After we get to the center, we want to decrement the number of blocks each time, which can be done by subtracting the row index from the total number of rows.

The code says it better, I think:

```
private static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Get grid size from user and keep it between 1 and the window width
        var gridSize = GetIntFromUser("Enter the size of the grid: ");
        gridSize = Math.Min(Console.WindowWidth - 1, Math.Max(1, gridSize));

        var grid = new bool[gridSize, gridSize];
        var center = (gridSize - 1) / 2;

        // Populate our grid with a diamond pattern
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < grid.GetLength(0); rowIndex++)
        {
            // Determine number of blocks to fill based on current row
            var fillAmount = (rowIndex <= center)
                ? rowIndex : grid.GetUpperBound(0) - rowIndex;

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex <= fillAmount; colIndex++)
            {
                grid[rowIndex, center - colIndex] = true;
                grid[rowIndex, center + colIndex] = true;
            }
        }

        // Display the final grid to the console
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                Console.Write(grid[row, col] ? "█" : " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and this is the helper function I used to get an integer from the user. It's pretty helpful to keep around because you don't have to do any validation in your main code:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int value;

    // Write the prompt text and get input from user
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // If input can't be converted to a double, keep trying
    while (!int.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        Console.Write($"'{input}' is not a valid number. Please try again: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Input was successfully converted!
    return value;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]